# Why can I access static member variables inside a static callback method without an instance variable?

Tags: c++, callback, static

This code is accessing a private member variable from a static callback method without an instance variable to properly scope it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() { }
        ~Foo() { }
        static int staticCallback(void *data);
        void myFunction(int (* func)(void*));
    private:
        static std::string mStr;
};

std::string Foo::mStr; // initialize static variables

void Foo::myFunction(int (*func)(void*))
{
    std::cout << "Invoke static callback function" << std::endl;
    Foo f;
    func(&f);
}

int Foo::staticCallback(void *data)
{
    Foo *p = (Foo *)data;
    std::string test("Shouldn't Foo::mStr be out of scope?");
    mStr = test;  // is this UB? thought I would need p->mStr here...
    std::cout << mStr << std::endl;
    std::cout << p->mStr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo f;
    f.myFunction(f.staticCallback);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to figure out if accessing the class private member variable `mStr` from inside a static callback method is allowed or is this undefined behavior?  I expected the compiler to complain when I attempted to access a class private member variable from inside a static callback method without an instance variable but it's working like I don't need it. Why?

Comment: It's not clear to me where the confusion is. Please explain what you think `static` in `static std::string mStr;` means, and from there we may be able to identify the cause of the misunderstanding.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I understood it to be a private member of the class, and static or not, I'm not sure why you can access it without an instance variable of that class.

Comment: @JustinRandall Well, `static int staticCallback(void *data);` is also a member of the class. But you seem fine with that being called without an instance. `static` means the same thing for data members as member functions. There is 1 "global" instance of this member and it's not associated with an instance of the `class`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So then essentially if you make a `private` member variable of a class `static`, it is globally accessible?

Comment: @JustinRandall Access specified has nothing to do with how `static` behaves. But, if you make it `public`, than yes it's essentially a cleaner global variable. If it's `private` than it's like a global variable but only your class has access to it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  Thank you for clearing it up for me.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I shamelessly stole the results of your revealing the true misunderstanding. Lets call it teamwork :P

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I don't mind at all. Thank you for formalizing the back-and-forth from the comments into an answer. I am actually the answer's upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment:

> I understood it to be a private member of the class, and static or not, I'm not sure why you can access it without an instance variable of that class.

First, the member is `static`, meaning you do not need an instance to access it. Same as for the `static` method.

So lets put `static` aside, then access is per class not per instance. It works just as you can access private members of instances other than `this` in non-static methods. For example:

```
struct foo {
    void add(foo b) { x += b.x; }
private:
    int x;
};
```

Nothing wrong here.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) (empahsize mine):

> All members of a class (bodies of member functions, initializers of member objects, and the entire nested class definitions) have access to all names **the class** can access.

Another comment:

> So then essentially if you make a private member variable of a class static, it is globally accessible?

No! You are accessing it inside a method of the class, not in global scope. If you tried to access it eg in `main` it would fail.

**PS:** even if it compiles, I would not write `f.staticCallback` but `Foo::staticCallback` instead. Imagine the callback would be called differently then `f.foo` is misleading. Some goes for `p->mStr` vs `Foo::mStr`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there seems to be some confusion here, and your code is a little strange.

Static methods are sort of like globals methods tied to your class. They do NOT work on a single instance. You can call a static method from main, for instance, like this:

```
int main(int, char **) {
    Foo::staticFunction(nullptr);
}
```

It's not really clear what you're ultimately trying to do.

Because mStr is static, it is available from both static and non-static methods. However, non-static fields are unavailable from static methods, as static methods don't have a "this".

Note that the compiler has no idea what a callback is. It sees a static method. At the time you define the method, it doesn't care how the method was invoked.